# Javascript value updating only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on adding an item into the cart. So far, I can select the quantity, it changes the data-quantity value in my Add to Cart button and when I click the button, it should serialize the data attributes and send them to my back-end via an ajax call. For the sake of this question, I will omit the ajax call and only alert the serialized data.

When I change the quantity, the value updates on the button's data-quantity attribute. So if I click Add to Cart, it will display the correct quantity.

The problem I'm having now is if I change the quantity again and although it changes the data-quantity attribute when I click on the Add to Cart button, it does not give the updated data-quantity value.

How can I fix this?

Code below:

```
$('.qtyBox').on('change', function(e){
  $(this).closest(".row").find('a').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
});

//Login User
$(".addToCart").click(function() {
  let data_array = new Array();

  let item = {};
  item['data-shop'] = $(this).data('shop');
  item['data-prod'] = $(this).data('prod');
  item['data-qty'] = $(this).data('quantity');

  data_array.push(item);
  let serialized = JSON.stringify(data_array);

  alert(serialized);
});


<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <input class="qtyBox" type="number" name="productQty" value="1" min="1" max="3">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <a data-shop="<?= $product['s_id'] ?>" data-prod="<?= $product['product_id']  ?>" data-quantity="3" class="modal-trigger waves-effect btn-small orange darken-2 text-normal action-btn right addToCart">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because even though jQuery's `.data()` method can *read* HTML5 data- attributes, it actually uses an internal store to set the value. Therefore, you should use `.data('quantity', <val>)` to set the value instead:

```
$('.qtyBox').on('change', function(e){
  $(this).closest(".row").find('a').data('quantity', $(this).val());
});
```